# How to start Emacs without the cmd.exe window (on MS Windows)?

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up

It says emacs/bin/emacs.exe. If it's not necesarily useful, I'd like to stop it from starting with emacs. The extra window is messing me up a bit.

Answer (score 41):

Instead of opening `emacs.exe` directly, open `runemacs.exe`. This will open Emacs without the extra window in the background.

Comment: The Windows installer for Emacs actually creates the shortcut to Emacs as `runemacs.exe`, yet the `cmd.exe` window still opens at launch time.

Comment: However, if you pin `runemacs.exe` to taskbar, clicking it will open a separate `emacs` item in taskbar, not overlaying. Overall I don't understand why the hassle of creating that cmd window in the first place.