# Avoid cmd window for pinned emacs on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows

This question [How to start Emacs without the cmd.exe window (on MS Windows)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20213/how-to-start-emacs-without-the-cmd-exe-window-on-ms-windows) adresses how you start emacs without a cmd window in the first place.

This works out nicely until you pin emacs to your task bar, close it and open it again. Now you have the pinned emacs icon and another icon (not grouped with the pinned one) for the actual emacs frame.

How do I convince Windows to group these two icons (and all further emacs frames) together?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Start Emacs by running `runemacs.exe` as describe in the link in the question above.
2. Right-click on the Emacs icon and pin it to the taskbar.
3. Right-click on the Emacs icon again, then right-click on the Emacs icon in the popup and select *Properties*.
4. In the *Properties* dialog, alter the Target to point to the `runemacs.exe` you want to use to start a new Emacs instance.
5. Click *OK*.

Comment: "Right-click -> pin" didn't work for me; __dragging__ the good icon onto the taskbar did.